# Login using Angular JS and Java

Tags: java, angularjs

I got to know somewhat about Angular JS. I have [watched this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM), but just basic only. I want to try out it in my Java application. I searched for a demo, but I don’t get any idea. So I am asking here.

I have Java entity baean model class called **`User`**, now it has just two fields.

```
String name;
String password;
```

I have service classes and daos for that to save data to a database using hibernate.

Now I want to try angularjs. I haven’t created any action class.

Here is the form in my HTML page

**index.html**

```
 <div ng-app class="container">
      <form class="form-signin" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="User name" required ng-model="name" name="name">
        <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" required name="password" ng-model="password">
        <br>
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button> or <a href="/signup">Signup</a>
      </form>
```

How can I use Angularjs to get the data and call action class? Based on success or error, how can I redirect to a success or error page?

Can someone give some idea(sample code) or some demo link(get some java object from HTML page, pass to java class redirect to some page based on return)? Because I don't find anyone. I want to learn how to use AngularJS using Java.

Comment: You need to provide some sort of HTTP API to your services, possibly by using a framework such as Spring MVC, or otherwise by writing a servlet.

Comment: I can write an action class. But how to pass the data (User object) from page to that action class using Angularjs?

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Comment: Ref This example Contains end to end flow https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login-angular . Includes login how to pass angular parameters and receive it in Java Spring boot and generate a token. After successful login how to redirect the user to other page in SPA

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example from one of my project, hopefully it will point you in the right direction, basically you have to use `$http` in your factory/service:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app').factory('myService', myService);
    function myService($http, config) {
        var service = {
        postData : postData
    }

    function postData(param) { 
            return $http.post(config.apiUrl + '/api/postData', param)
                    .then(function(result) {
                        return result;
                });
        }

    return service;
    }
})();
```

Don't worry about the `config` and `config.apiUrl` - thats basically = `"http://localhost:8080/"` + your api url ex. `getData/postData` etc. You just put your full URL `$http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/postData', param)`. If you don't want to pass parameter just leave the `param` part out.

Or if you want a simple one that you can call directly from your controller:

```
$scope.postData = function(){
    $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/api/postData",
    data: $scope.data
}).then(function(response){
  console.log(response);
      if(response.data.success){
        // do your stuff...
      } else if(response.data.error) {
        // or do this stuff...
      }
    });
  }
```

The data object `$scope.data` will hold your username and password:

```
$scope.data.username = "username";
$scope.data.password = "password";
```